# Can't Tell Where IIS Inheritance is coming from

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, iis, web-config

This is on a Windows 2012 Server. I have a vendor application that "installed" a site to my IIS. It placed it under the default website as an application. However I want to move it to a different website with a different binding.

The only problem I can see so far is that it has a default document setting that is being inherited however I cannot tell from where it's being inherited. The setting isn't in the web.config. When I create a new site under my preferred binding I get the regular inheritances such as index.htm, index.aspx, etc. When I add the default document manually the original site will get an error about duplicate web.config entries and crash the app pool.

Now so far I've looked and the default document setting is not in the app's web.config, it's not in the parent site's web.config, it's not on any of the other sites on the IIS server up the hierarchy. It's not on the machine.config or server web.config in the windows\microsoft.net\framework64/v4.0.30319\Config folder either.

I can get around this problem without too much difficulty, but I'm just really curious to learn how this setting is being inherited and from where. Can anyone point me to any other places to check?

Comment: Have you checked the application host configuration file? On IIS 7+ it is located in %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

Comment: yes that was it, I had forgotten about that one. Can you re-write this as an answer to the question so I can mark you correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the application host configuration file. On IIS 7+ it is located in %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config